Generic enum bean producer
I'm trying to write a generic enum producer;every injection point declare a different enum-type and value is resolved againts a set of values declared elsewhere (not so important).
I'm stuck writing generic enum @Produces:
@ApplicationScoped
class MyBean {
  @Inject
  @EnumProperty
  MyEnum myEnumProperty;

  @Inject
  @EnumProperty
  AnotherEnum anotherEnumProperty;
}

@Qualifier
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface EnumProperty {
    @Nonbinding
    public String name() default ""; 
}

@ApplicationScoped
public GenericEnumProducer {

  @Produces @EnumProperty
  Enum enumProducer(InjectionPoint ip) { 
    Field f = (Field) injectionTarget;
    Class<Enum<?>> enumClass = (Class<Enum<?>>) f.getType();
    return getPropertyFromSystemAndConvertToEnum();
  }

  @Produces @EnumProperty
  Object objectEnumProducer(InjectionPoint ip) { 
    Field f = (Field) injectionTarget;
    Class<Enum<?>> enumClass = (Class<Enum<?>>) f.getType();
    return getPropertyFromSystemAndConvertToEnum();
  }

  @Produces @EnumProperty
  <T extends Enum<?>> T genericEnumProducer(InjectionPoint ip) { 
    Field f = (Field) injectionTarget;
    Class<Enum<?>> enumClass = (Class<Enum<?>>) f.getType();
    return getPropertyFromSystemAndConvertToEnum();
  }
}

I have compilation-time exceptions

Producer method java.lang.Enum<?>
genericEnumProducer(jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionPoint ip)
declared on class MyBean$GenericEnumProducer
contains a parameterized type with a wildcard. This type is not a
legal bean type according to CDI specification.

or

Unsatisfied dependency for type
MyBean$MyEnum and qualifiers
[@EnumProperty]

injection target: MyBean#value
declared on CLASS bean [types=[MyBean, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any],
target=MyBean]


Any advice?

Try <T extends Enum>

I have already tried (it's the last method in GenericEnumProducer) and doesn't work

last method has wildcard ?. Try 'T'  insteat of

Still not working:
A type variable is not a legal bean type: T genericEnumProducer(jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionPoint ip)

I don't think this can work because the bean type you have is not a legal bean type, see this part of specification. In a nutshell, a type variable or a parameterized type containing a wildcard are not legal bean types.
What might be useful to you is that a bean type can be a parameterized type with actual type parameters and type variables.
Lastly, such producer will always have to have scope @Dependent but you already have that.

I think it's possible hier is example Generic CDI producer method not working as expected
in your case:
public class Wrapper<T extends Enum<T>> {
     public final Enum<T> bean;
     public Wrapper(Enum<T> bean){
       this.bean = bean;
     }
   }
...
@Produces @EnumProperty
   <T extends Enum<T>> Wrapper<T> genericEnumProducer(InjectionPoint ip) {
       Field f = (Field) injectionTarget;
       Class<Enum<T>> enumClass = (Class<Enum<T>>) f.getType();
       return getPropertyFromSystemAndConvertToEnum();
   }

